# Need a calculated column to pull value from previous row, different column, when NULL, use previous value

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

Spotfire rookie here.

i'm trying to populate a calculated column with a value from another calculated column.

The goal is to populate the [my_row_id] with [my_first_reading] and where [my_first_reading] is NULL.

The code below is populating all of the NULL's from [my_first_reading] as 1 as shown in the image below.

[calculated column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLV5g.jpg)

the code for above is:

If([my_first_reading] is not NULL ,[my_first_reading],First([row_id] ))

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

| Parm | first_read | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| start | 1 | 1 |
| read2 |  | 1 |
| read3 |  | 1 |
| start | 2 | 2 |
| read2 |  | 2 |

first_read:

case
when Find("start",[Parm])>0 then RowId()
else NULL
END

ID: LastValidBefore([first_read])

struggled with this for a while.  found a similar approach on the forum.

let me know if you have a better solution.  thanks!